# About Nginx configuration to run a Laravel application

Tags: php, linux, laravel, nginx, configuration

[Laravel Official Site Configuration](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/deployment#nginx)

```
server {
    ...

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
    error_page 404 /index.php;

    ...
}
```

I want to know if the code `error_page 404 /index.php;` is redundant, because of `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;` can deal with all the uri that file not exists.
If it is not redundant, in what scenarios it could work.

Comment: It will work as an HTTP 404 error page for any location other than `location / { ... }`